# Elm 0.19 --optimize and ports

Tags: elm, webpack-4

According to https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/optimize:

> Step two is to call uglifyjs with a bunch of special flags. The flags unlock optimizations that are unreliable in normal JS code, but because Elm does not have side-effects, they work fine for us!

However what about ports? The ports might have side effects. Won't this advice be problematic if one uses ports in ELM?

If so how would one go about splitting the ports out of the elm.js file.

PS I am busing https://github.com/elm-community/elm-webpack-loader and its get bundled into 1 big js file.

Comment: It may be problematic if you minimize your js code using the same flags as with compiled elm code.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions at https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/optimize are for optimizing (size wise, not performance) code generated by the elm compiler *only*. **Do not** use those flags to optimize javascript written by hand or from other libraries. If you want to optimize and combine your elm with external javascript into one file, optimization needs to happen separately on your elm compiler generated javascript and all other javascript, *and then* combined into one file.

Which means:

The modules you write in elm for ports can be optimized like any other elm code.  The *javascript* you write to interact with those ports / subscriptions must not be optimized like elm generated javascript.